# Calculating Receptive Field

Tags: conv-neural-network, receptive-field

I want to calculate the dimensions of the receptive field for a 3 layer CNN with filter sizes of 3x3, a default stride of 1, except for 2 for the 2nd layer.

My calculations (drawing) were
1st layer: 3x3
2nd layer: 7x7
3rd layer: 15x15

I am not sure if I am right though.